# How to combine not disjoint sets efficiently without a brute force approach?

Tags: algorithm, performance, set

Let's say that I have a set of sets. Each of them composed by two or more subsets.

For example:

S = {S1, S2, S3}

S1 = [0,1,2,3] = {S11 = [0,1], S12 = [2,3]}

S2 = [2,3,4,5] = {S21 = [2,3], S22 = [4,5]}

S3 = [4,5,6,7] = {S31 = [4,5], S32 = [6,7]}

As you notice, the intersection between S1-S2 and S2-S3 is not empty.

I am implementing a program and I would like to generate these results:

1) S11 [0,1], S2 [2,3,4,5], S32 [6,7]

2) S1 [0,1,2,3], S3 [4,5,6,7]

I want every result to contain all numbers without any intersection allowed (if I can not accomplish that with the bigger sets, I can use their subsets).

Can you think of a clever algorithm to do this?

I feel like it is somehow a known problem, but as I am not a math expert, I do not know what to google for.

For now, I am implementing this with a brute force approach (I try all combinations), but it is not efficient.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What is `S1`, is it `{0,1,2,3}` or is it `{{0,1}, {2,3}}`?

Answer (score 0):

Solvable with a subroutine for [exact cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover) (conversely, exact cover is easily reducible to this problem). Basically we can just flatten the set structure, but we need to add some new elements and sets to ensure that at most one set from each family is chosen.

For example:

```
{s1}
{0, 1, 2, 3, s1}
{0, 1, s1}
{2, 3, s1}
{s2}
{2, 3, 4, 5, s2}
{2, 3, s2}
{4, 5, s2}
{s3}
{4, 5, 6, 7, s3}
{4, 5, s3}
{6, 7, s3}
```

The elements `s1, s2, s3` are artificial (distinct from the existing elements).